# Yeoman generator - How to change the content of some file depending on a prompted param

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am writing a generator in which a user will be prompted a param, let's call it `option`. Depending on its answer I want to change one of the output files:

**SomeClass.java**

```
public class SomeClass{

    //if option=x I don't want to include this attribute:
    private String field1;

    //if option=x I want to generate an attribute with the value of the promted attribute
    private String ${info};
```

How can I do the actions described in the comments above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**index.js**

Here in the `prompting()` method you will declared all your prompts and the type of prompt with names included. Then in `writing()` you will pass those to the template which here is `MyClass.java`

```
module.exports = class extends Generator {
  prompting() {
    // Have Yeoman greet the user.
    this.log(yosay(
      'Welcome to the remarkable ' + chalk.red('generator-react-starter-kit-relay-container') + ' generator!'
    ));

    const prompts = [{
      type: 'input',
      name: 'info',
      message: 'INFO IN YOUR CLASS'
    }, {
      type: 'confirm',
      name: 'x',
      message: 'YOUR OPTION X'
    }];

    return this.prompt(prompts).then(props => {
      this.props = props;
    });
  }

  writing() {
    this.fs.copyTpl(
      this.templatePath('MyClass.js'),
      this.destinationPath(<YOUR DESTINATION PATH>),
      {
        info: this.props.info,
        x: this.props.x
      }
    );
  } 
};
```

**templates/MyClass.java**

```
public class MyClass{

    <% if (x) { %>
    private String <%= info %>;
    <% } else { %>
    private String field1;
    <% } %>

}
```

Comment: Oops, I did not see that this was asked 21 hours ago.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your answer, I answered myself at the same time as you. Anyway, I'll accept yours for taking the time to help out ;-)

Comment: Yeah, your update might have pushed this question to top in the list, so I assumed it was a new question. Anyway, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

**SomeClass.java:**

```
public class SomeClass{

    <%_ if (option == 'x') { _%>
    private String field1;
    <%_ } _%>

    private String <%= nombre %>;
```

And this is the generator code:

```
module.exports = class extends Generator {
  prompting() {
    // Have Yeoman greet the user.
    this.log(yosay(
      'Welcome to the super-duper ' + chalk.red('generator-mygenerator') + ' generator!'
    ));

    const prompts = [{
      type: 'input',
      name: 'option',
      message: 'Option?',
      default: 'x'
    },
    {
      type: 'input',
      name: 'info',
      message: 'Field name?',
      default: 'field'
    }
    ];

    return this.prompt(prompts).then(props => {
      this.props = props;
    });
  }

  writing() {
    this.fs.copyTpl(
      this.templatePath('SomeClass.java'),
      this.destinationPath('SomeClass.java'), this.props);
  }
}
```